# How do I disconnect AWS in Facebook CAPI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook-conversions-api

So my boss wants to connect Facebook cAPI on Gohighlevel instead of AWS. He mentioned that we need to delete an "instance". I found a tab inside AWS that says "instance" and "instance types". I don't know where to go from there or if I should start there.

My boss suggested to watch a YT vid he provided and from there we will know where to delete the "instance". I watched the vid and found the instance tab but I don't know where to go from there and I don't want to touch anything I'm not supposed to. I found a vid how to setup cAPI in GHL so my goal right now is how can I disconnect AWS in Facebook cAPI.